# Remove registered server from Canonical's Landscape

Tags: ubuntu, landscape

I have a free account of landscape with 2 servers registered. One of them was replaced with a new one because serious hardware problems. When the new server was online and ready to replace tall functionality, the old server was shutdown and retired, but it still appears in the registered machines, and keeps sending warnings. How can this server be unregistered?

Answer (score 0):

Log in [here](https://landscape.canonical.com/)
Next to your name, on top, there's a link, "System Management". You should be able to remove it there.

Comment: Wich option? I show a list of servers but no 'remove' button.

Comment: [link](http://img24.imageshack.us/i/landscapes.jpg/)

Comment: Just uncheck the box at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Thanks, but that has no effect. Finally found the answer: select the machine, then go to edit, when in edit mode there is the 'remove link'